# Object creation chaining pattern

Tags: c#, xml, design-patterns

I have an XML file with complex structure. Following is just a small sample.

```
    <MainTag>
        <Tag1 name="">
            <SubTag1_1 msgType="">
            <SubTag1_2 storeId="abc" abc=""/>
            </Tag1>
            <Tag2 msgType="">
                <SubTag2_1 name="" cap="" value="#"/>
                <SubTag2_2=""/>
            </Tag2> 
        </Tag1>

        <Tag3 name="">
            <SubTag3>
                <SubTag3_1 msgType="A" value="1">
                    <SubSubTag3 name="" xml="" sap="" time_delta="0" time_absolute="2"/>
                    <SubSubTag3 name="" xml="" sap="" type="transmit" time_delta="5" time_absolute="2"/>
                </SubTag3_1 >
                <SubTag3_2 msgType="" value="1">
                    <SubSubTag3 name="" xml="" sap="" type="receive" time_delta="0" time_absolute="2"/>
          </SubTag3_2>
      </SubTag3>
   </Tag3>
</MainTag>
```

I have to create the above XML file multiple times for different set of data. Instead of having a single class to take all the data and write the XML file, I have created a kind of object graph. Each main Tag is represented by a class. For example

Class MainTag will have a reference of classes Tag1 and Tag3. Tag1 class will have reference to sub classes SubTag1, Tag2 etc. Further, each class implements IXmlSerializable interface which makes writing the XML file pretty easy and nicely divided. Dividing the classes also helps if the XML structure is changed.

Questions:

1) Is the approach correct to divide the XML structure into a set of classes ?

2) Since I have a lot of classes, I have to initialize all the class structure (object graph). Once the data (that i want to insert in the xml) is ready, I want to start the initialization of whole object graph. Once initialization is done, I just want to write the XML using IXmlSerializable interface .Is there any design pattern for the kind of object initialization I am using ? Currently, I am just doing the following. This looks strange.

```
class MainTag: XmlBase
{
    List<Tag1> Tag1List{ get; set; }
    Tag1 t;

    public MainTag() : base()
    {
       t = new Tag1();
       //Do processing and populate the properties of MainTag
    }
}

class Tag1 : XmlBase
{
  List<SubTag1_1> subtags;
  SubTag1_1 s;

  public Tag1()
  {
      s = new SubTag1_1();
      //Do processing and populate the properties of Tag1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Composite Pattern

I'm not a c# developer but you could create an XMLTag class for each tag type you have and a CompositeXMLTag that inherits from XMLTag to aggregate the XMLTag objects.

Then you create a class for the initialization of the tags tree

For more information about the Composite pattern http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185797/Composite-Design-Pattern

EDIT: I'm not an c# developer, so here is an java example

```
public interface CompositeXMLTag {

    public void addTag(CompositeXMLTag tag);

    public void serialize();
}



public class Tag1 implements CompositeXMLTag {

    private List<CompositeXMLTag> tags = new ArrayList<CompositeXMLTag>();
    private String name;

    /* getters and setters */

    @Override
    public void addTag(CompositeXMLTag tag) {
        this.tags.add(tag);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize() {
        for (CompositeXMLTag compositeXMLTag : tags) {
            compositeXMLTag.serialize();
        }
    }
}

public class SubTag1_1 implements CompositeXMLTag{

    private List<CompositeXMLTag> tags = new ArrayList<CompositeXMLTag>();
    private String storeId;
    private String abc;

    /* getters and setters */

    @Override
    public void addTag(CompositeXMLTag tag) {
        this.tags.add(tag);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize() {
        for (CompositeXMLTag compositeXMLTag : tags) {
            compositeXMLTag.serialize();
        }
    }
}

public class Client {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
                CompositeXMLTag tag1 = new Tag1();

                tag1.addTag(new SubTag1_1());

                tag1.serialize();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Isn't composite pattern for relationship between objects ?

Comment: You are suggesting that for each XMLTag I create a class. Then create another class which will act as parent called CompositeXMLTag. But as per composite pattern, which class will act as a leaf ?

Comment: I am supposing that you can insert subtags in every tag you have, if that is the case you'll only have composite classes, not leaves.
If for example SubTag1_1 and SubTag1_2 doesn't accept childs, they will be the leaf classes.

Comment: From the GOF

"Composite Patter: Compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Composite lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly". It will be easy to add objects into your tree and to serialize them. It also prevents you to instantiate the childs in the parent classes as it provides an addChild method in the composite